# How to dynamic import in an object file with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've set a RouteConfig.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard.js'
import ProjectDetails from './components/project/ProjectDetails.js'
const RouteList = [
  { component: Dashboard, path: '/', exact: true },
  { component: ProjectDetails, path: '/details', exact: true }
]

const Routes = RouteList.map(route => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      component={route.component}
      key={route.component}
      exact={route.exact}
    ></Route>
  )
})

export default Routes
```

and it works perfectly for myself. However my code going to be grow and I'll import tons of lines of components. therefore I've tried to dynamic import with ReactRouter like VueRouter but it didn't worked.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
const RouteList = [
  {
    component: () => import('./components/dashboard/Dashboard.js'),
    path: '/',
    exact: true
  },
  {
    component: () => import('./components/project/ProjectDetails.js'),
    path: '/details',
    exact: true
  }
]

const Routes = RouteList.map(route => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      component={route.component}
      key={route.component}
      exact={route.exact}
    ></Route>
  )
})

export default Routes
```

I wonder if is there a way to make some dynamic import in an object file. Thank you all.

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-code-splitting/

Comment: You might consider using `React.lazy` `const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));`. Keep in mind your router will have to be wrapped with `<Suspense>`